# Create references with part number and frame number

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, parts

I created a beamer theme which uses parts (for lecture slides) and where the slides are numbered using the part number and the frame number. The frame number is reset at the beginning of each part.

The problem is, when I create a reference with `\ref`, only the frame number is shown.

How can I show both the part number and the frame number?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\AtBeginPart{\setcounter{framenumber}{0}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\slidenumber}
{slide \ifnum\c@part=0
\insertframenumber
\else
\insertpartnumber-\insertframenumber
\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\frame{\slidenumber, ref: \ref{one-two}}
\frame{\slidenumber}
\part{one}
\frame{\slidenumber}
\frame[label=one-two]{\slidenumber}
\part{two}
\frame{\slidenumber}
\frame{\slidenumber}
\end{document}
```

This example shows "ref: 2" on the first slide, but I would like it to show "ref: 1-2".

I guess I'll have to somehow redefine `\label` and/or `\ref`, but sadly, this is way beyond my TeX/LaTeX skills.

Comment: Your code just changes the slidenumber which is shown on every frame where you include command `\slidenumber` but not the real slide number which is stored in .aux file and later referenced by `\ref`. But I cannot help with this part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginPart{\setcounter{framenumber}{0}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\slidenumber}{%
slide \ifnum\c@part=0\relax
  \insertframenumber
\else
  \insertpartnumber-\insertframenumber
\fi}
\def\mynumberwithin#1#2{\@ifundefined{c@#1}{\@nocounterr{#1}}{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#2}{\@nocnterr{#2}}{%
  \@addtoreset{#1}{#2}%
  \toks@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname the#1\endcsname
    {\expandafter\noexpand\csname the#2\endcsname
     -\the\toks@}}}}
\pretocmd{\part}{%
\ifnum\c@part=0\relax
  \mynumberwithin{framenumber}{part}
\fi%
}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frame{\slidenumber, ref~\ref{two}, ref~\ref{one-two} and ref~\ref{two-two}}
\frame[label=two]{\slidenumber}

\part{one}
\frame{\slidenumber}
\frame[label=one-two]{\slidenumber}

\part{two}
\frame{\slidenumber}
\frame[label=two-two]{\slidenumber}

\end{document}
```

An image showing the produced cross-references:

[image]

The idea is simply to set the `framenumber` counter to be prepended by the `part` counter. I used a similar mechanism as the used by `amstex`'s `\numberwithin`, but with a variation to use a hyphen instead of a dot. Provision was made to make this change just after a `\part` command has been actually used so eventual references to frames before the first part will produce just the frame number.

Notice that with these settings, there's no need for your \slidenumber command, since now you can simply use \theframenumber:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginPart{\setcounter{framenumber}{0}}
\makeatletter
\def\mynumberwithin#1#2{\@ifundefined{c@#1}{\@nocounterr{#1}}{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#2}{\@nocnterr{#2}}{%
  \@addtoreset{#1}{#2}%
  \toks@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname the#1\endcsname
    {\expandafter\noexpand\csname the#2\endcsname
     -\the\toks@}}}}
\pretocmd{\part}{%
\ifnum\c@part=0\relax
  \mynumberwithin{framenumber}{part}
\fi%
}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frame{\theframenumber, ref~\ref{two}, ref~\ref{one-two} and ref~\ref{two-two}}
\frame[label=two]{\theframenumber}

\part{one}
\frame{\theframenumber}
\frame[label=one-two]{\theframenumber}

\part{two}
\frame{\theframenumber}
\frame[label=two-two]{\theframenumber}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, this works great! ... except ... when I'm using `\appendix` this is treated like yet another `\part`. Would it be possible to show something like "A-1", "A-2" etc. in the appendix? I'm already re-defining `\appendix`, so I could easily add something there.

Comment: @Matthias You're welcome! For the case of the appendices, you can do something like `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\pretocmd{\appendix}{%
  \counterwithout{framenumber}{part}
}{}{}
\apptocmd{\appendix}{\setcounter{part}{0}\renewcommand\thepart{\Alph{part}}}{}{}` (or something similar if you are already redefining `\appendix`).

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! I just added `\renewcommand{\thepart}{A}` to my re-definition of `\appendix`, because I don't want to use further parts within the appendix anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask yet again, but another issue came up: When using `\includeonly`, the slide numbers using `\theframenumber` don't work anymore. Strangely, it still works for part 0 and part 1, but starting with part 2, `\theframenumber` is just a single number continuing from the last frame number in part 1. The numbers inserted with `\ref` are still correct. Do you have an idea what could be the problem? If my situation is not quite clear, I can create a new question with a MWE.

Comment: I found a solution to my `\includeonly` problem, but it's not very nice: I have to use the `\slidenumber` macro to get part number and frame number and I have to use `\AtBeginPart{\setcounter{framenumber}{0}}` to reset the frame number (which happens automatically if I _don't_ use `\includeonly`). Is there a better way?

Comment: @Matthias Sorry, but I hadn't seen your previous message. Perhaps in this case I think it would be better, as you said, to open a fresh new question as a follow-up to this one and include there a MWE illustrating the problem.

Comment: Hey @GonzaloMedina I am having the same problem and when I compile your minimal example, I get ", 1, ref 2, ref 4 and ref 6" on the first page and not 1-2/2-2 for 4/6. As your solution is now some years old, maybe something has changed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interestingly, I found out that moving away from the label-option of the frame and using \label{} outside after the frame solves the issue. Yet, for the last frame it does not work surprisingly. So referencing the label of the last frame tells me it does not exist. Any ideas?

Comment: For the last frame it works, i one adds some invisible text afterwards the label...